# AS3 - URLRequest not working

Tags: cross-domain, flash, urlrequest

My flash SWF needs to load "photo.jpg" using URLRequest but in vain. Heres how I am doing it

```
imLoader = new Loader();
imLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, imageLoaded);
imLoader.load(new URLRequest("photo.jpg"));
```

The SWF and photo are both located in the same directory on my localhost server. When i render it in the browser, photo doesn't load. But when i do it manually by simply opening the  SWF, photo loads up properly.

Is it something related to crossdomain or what is the problem?

Comment: I think there was some kind of setting that you need to make if you swf does some network operations. But I don't know where. I've seen it somewhere but I forgot. Maybe it helps if you know that there is this setting (maybe in FlashDevelop). I had the same error. While debugging URL was opening and after upload it stopped working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The path is relative to the HTML document. So if your image and SWF are not in the same directory as the HTML you need to provide a path (absolute or relative to the HTML).

So if your SWF and image are in 'media' directory you would need:

```
imLoader.load(new URLRequest("media/photo.jpg"));
//or
imLoader.load(new URLRequest("/media/photo.jpg"));
//or (if SWF and image are on different server)
imLoader.load(new URLRequest("http://www.domain.com/media/photo.jpg"));
```